# Cairo line misses statring or ending pixel

Tags: gtk3, cairo

I paint lines via Cairo API on Ubuntu 19.10 x64. I first call `cairo_move_to(...)` for starting point, then call `cairo_line_to(...)` for ending point, then call `cairo_stroke()`. I add 0.5 increment to all coords so line looks sharp. I set line with to 1.

Problem: sometimes when I run my app, line misses final pixel, sometimes (in another work session, e.g. day after) it misses starting pixel of line. Why? How can I paint line always missing only fixed pixel, or not missing pixels?

I use Lazarus 2.0.

```
const
  PixelOffset=0.5;
var
  FX, FY: Double;
  X0, Y0: Double;
begin
  cairo_get_current_point(Widget, @FX, @FY);
  X0 := FX - PixelOffset;
  Y0 := FY - PixelOffset;

  cairo_move_to(Widget, X + PixelOffset, Y + PixelOffset);
  cairo_line_to(Widget, X0 + PixelOffset, Y0 + PixelOffset);
  cairo_stroke(Widget);
  cairo_move_to(Widget, X + PixelOffset, Y + PixelOffset);
end;
```

libgtk-3-0:amd64 3.24.8-1ubuntu1

Comment: Do you call `cairo_set_antialias()` anywhere to try to disabling antialias? If so, I guess you are seeing rounding issues and should try an offset of e.g. 0.7 (but this my cause to include a pixel too much somewhere if you have non-integer positions).

Comment: @UliSchlachter No, I didn't call `cairo_set_antialias`, and even if I call it, it don't make result look better.

Comment: @UliSchlachter Changing PixelOffset don't help too, anyway one of pixels is missing.